# Rhino Mocks: Mocking HttpRequestBase.Files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload, rhino-mocks

I have a view & controller that allow the user to upload a file to the server. This is done in the view using an `input type='file'` and in the controller by getting the value of `Request.Files` (`HttpRequestBase`, returning a `HttpFileCollectionWrapper`).

I am having difficulty mocking this using Rhino Mocks.

```
HttpContextBase mockHttpContext = MockRepository.GenerateMock<HttpContextBase>();
HttpRequestBase mockRequest = MockRepository.GenerateMock<HttpRequestBase>();
mockHttpContext.Stub(x => x.Request).Return(mockRequest);

mockRequest.Stub(x => x.HttpMethod).Return("GET");

// Next line fails -  throws MissingMethodException
// (Can't find a constructor with matching arguments)
HttpFileCollectionWrapper files =
    MockRepository.GenerateMock<HttpFileCollectionWrapper>();

files.Stub(x => x.Count).Return(1);

mockRequest.Stub(x => x.Files).Return(files);
```

The constructor for `HttpFileCollectionWrapper` requires an `HttpFileCollection`, however this has an `internal` constructor.

Can anyone suggest how to get this approach, or a variant of it, to work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mock `HttpFileCollectionBase` instead of `HttpFileCollectionWrapper`:

```
var filesMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<HttpFileCollectionBase>();
filesMock.Stub(x => x.Count).Return(1);
mockRequest.Stub(x => x.Files).Return(filesMock);
```